# Dynamicaly adding rows to html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I been trying to build a html table dynamical. The number of rows the table should currently have is based on how many songs are in the user's music database. So i create a PHP method to count the number of song in a XML file. Which I assure you works perfectly fine. The PHP method returns a number. 
I send that number to my JavaScript code to add a row to the html table. Hope that wasn't confusing... but its not updating and I don't know why. Please take a look at my code.

#### JavaScript method

```
    function addRow(s,a,n){
        document.write(n);
        var table =document.getElementById("myLibrary");
        //default is 1
        var NumOfRows =n;
        var row = table.insertRow(NumOfRows);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = s;
        cell2.innerHTML =a;
        cell3.innerHTML =  "<button onclick='deleteRow(this)'>delete</button>";
    }
```

#### php method

```
$num=numOfSongs($u);
echo "<script> addRow('".$s."','".$a."','".$num."'); </script>";
```

Comment: `document.write(n);` will clear the entire content of the document if called after the load event has occurred. Write to the console or use an alert instead.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
table.insertRow(NumOfRows)
```

Seems to assume that insertRow() takes a parameter to create multiple rows.  This is not the case.  It takes a parameter to offset the insertion of the row (should be -1 in your case to put at end).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

You will need to create a for loop that loops n times.  In each loop you will create a new row and insert the cells and data.

Your code might look something like this.

```
function addRow(s,a,n){
    document.write(n);
    var table = document.getElementById("myLibrary");
    //default is 1
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = s;
        cell2.innerHTML =a;
        cell3.innerHTML = "<button onclick='deleteRow(this)'>delete</button>";
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yqb6b2ar/

Comment: Your usage of deleteRow() is similarly incorrect I believe btw.    You could use the i variable to create an ID and do the call similarly to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) or use i to work out the index of the table row.

Comment: Please don't reference [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com), instead link to the appropriate standard or specification, or to [*MDN:HTMLTableElement/insertRow*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) for further information and examples. Note that the index is optional and if omitted, defaults to -1.

Comment: Hi RobG, may I ask why I should not link to w3schools?    It, btw, suggests that index is only optional in certain browsers.  That seems like a useful bit of info (assuming it's not entirely wrong)

Comment: Actually MDN also suggests it is not always optional too.

Comment: Oh I see you have provided a link to an explanation about w3schools.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### upate##

braks was correct "seems to assume that insertRow() takes a parameter to create multiple rows. This is not the case. " Although this code just duplicates the same row which isn't what i wanted for future readers this link help me soo much
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp